# Deciding on a Upgrade path for a Laptop Hybrid HDD

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, upgrade, sshd

How do I find out what drives I can replace my laptop Hybrid HDD with,
currently i'm using a **'Seagate ST1000LM014'** (8GB MLC SSD 64mb cache 2.5" 5400rpm Hybrid HDD).

Would something like a **'Seagate ST2000LX001** work? (FireCuda SATA 6Gb/s 2.5" Hybrid Gaming Hard Drive)

Does it matter what kind of drive I use?

Can I use any drive as long as it's 2.5" and SATA?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use any drive as long as it's 2.5" and SATA?

Most of the time, yes. There are three standard drive thicknesses:

> - 12.5 mm - these are the Super-Phat drives that probably only larger laptops (DTRs and workstations) can fit. They usually have three platters instead of two, enabling higher capacity.
> - 9.5 mm - this is the most common size and should fit most laptops without problems.
> - 7 mm - these slim drives are used in thinner laptops (like ultraportables). Most SSDs are also in this size, and usually include a plastic bumper to increase the thickness to 9.5 mm in case the HDD mounting system requires it.
>
> <sup>[[source]](https://superuser.com/a/532199/194694)</sup>

Measure your original drive's thickness. Most likely it's 9.5 mm. 7 mm will fit in too. Some 7 mm SSDs come with a spacer to compensate the extra 2.5 mm, but it's not always necessary because the drive is secured with screws anyway.

Comment: The ST1000LM014 is 9.5mm as far as i'm aware, the ST2000LX001 is 7mm. so the size should be fine. Is there anything else I should be aware of?, Any recommendations for drives ?

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic here, but [Hardware Recommendations SE](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) may be helpful (read [their guidelines](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting there). Personally I'd avoid Seagate because of their relatively high failure rates. Hybrid drives also had gained some bad rep in the past years because of their unpredictable failures, but that may have improved.